# Does Android Studio provide a way to escape strings?

Tags: android, string, android-studio, escaping

I have a long string, and the compiler's complaining that there are unescaped apostrophes in it.

This seems like the kind of thing Android Studio should offer as a function: Escape this string.

Does it? I've looked in the doc and posted on the IRC channel.

Bonus question: What's the most active Android-dev forum? I don't know the best place to ask noob-level questions.

Thanks!

Comment: what's the string?

Comment: It's several paragraphs of text that contain normal constructions like "won't," and quote marks and other things.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't, refer [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#FormattingAndStyling)

> When a string contains characters that have special usage in XML or
> Android, you **MUST** escape the characters

I think you already are on the most active forum for developers. Another one that I know is https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/

Comment: Because I'm creating a string resource, not doing setText. And thanks for the referral to Reddit; should've thought of that.

Comment: No, there isn't. When a string contains characters that have special usage in XML or Android, you must escape the characters.

Comment: Pretty dumb not to have this function in the IDE. Thanks for the reply, though!